# About canonical linear programs.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming

Starting out with linear programming, I'm having some questions about canonical linear programs:

- Do all linear programs have a canonical form? So far I couldn't figure an example stating otherwise.
- Can a linear program have different (multiple) canonical forms? I guess the answer is yes. Are all forms equally good for solving the program? Is there any relevant difference?
- A "basic feasible solution" is a feasible solution where the non-basic variables are equalled to 0. Is there **only one** "basic feasible solution" for each canonical linear program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answers are: 1) YES; 2) YES/more or less/not much ; 3) NO.

You an easily find all the details on any standard textbook as

"Combinatorial Optimization: Algorithms and Complexity"
Book by Christos Papadimitriou and Kenneth Steiglitz

or

Linear and Nonlinear Programming: Second Edition
by David G. Luenberger

but the Internet is full of material on that.